# Mongo aggregate $or and $match from array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to find documents by combining $match and $or in aggregation pipeline?

Array filters.year:

```
[ { '$gte': '2015' },
  { '$gte': '2010', '$lte': '2015' },
  { '$gte': '2005', '$lte': '2010' },
  { '$gte': '2000', '$lte': '2005' },
  { '$lte': '2000' }
]
```

Code:

```
const query = [
{$match: {'active': filters.active}},
{
  $lookup: {
    from        : 'yachts',
    localField  : 'yachtId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as          : 'yacht'
  }
},
     {$match: { $or: [{'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': filters.year}]}}
]
```

Does not return any documents. Am i missing something?

Comment: What is `filters.active` and `filters.year`?

Comment: it's coming from front end, just ignore it, filter is an object with `{active: true, year:[]}`. It went through copy-paste, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resulting `$match` stage looks like this:

```
{ $or: [
  { 'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': [
    { '$gte': '2015' },
    { '$gte': '2010', '$lte': '2015' },
    { '$gte': '2005', '$lte': '2010' },
    { '$gte': '2000', '$lte': '2005' },
    { '$lte': '2000' }
   ] }
]}
```

While it needs to be:

```
{ $or: [
  { 'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': { '$gte': '2015' } },
  { 'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': { '$gte': '2010', '$lte': '2015' } },
  { 'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': { '$gte': '2005', '$lte': '2010' } },
  { 'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': { '$gte': '2000', '$lte': '2005' } },
  { 'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': { '$lte': '2000' } }
]}
```

If you want to write it concisely using your `filters`, you can do something like this:

```
{$match: { $or: filters.year.map(condition => {
  return {'yacht.specifications.constructionYear': condition}
})}}
```

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm. Can't believe this went under my eyes...